# Why doesn't Stack Trace show up in Nsight Correlation Pane?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, profiler, nsight

I'm using NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition to profile CUDA kernels - and for some reason "Stack Trace" doesn't appear under "cudaLaunch" in the Correlation Pane when I select a kernel from the "Compute" row. I want to be able to jump from the debugger to the source code as in this tutorial (go to 9:30):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt7Hvj4oviQ&feature=player_detailpage

I'm guessing I've screwed up a setting somewhere... Any help is appreciated. I'm using Nsight 3.1 with VS 2012 Pro and CUDA 5.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might've missed the setting in the activity page.  Please look at ~5:25 in that video for the specific settings.

With Nsight 3.1 VSE, we removed the 'actions' column because other than opening it in the editor there was not much 'action', and it was taking space. Instead, this pane now behaves like the Visual Studio call stack, where you can double click on each row to open the file.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: actually, now the stack trace shows up... but not the "actions" column containing the button that links back to source code. I believe I've followed the exact steps as the tutorial. Any thoughts?

Comment: Clicking rows in the stack doesn't seem to take me anywhere - but maybe I'm clicking the wrong thing. Also, no need to respond to both this post and the one on the NVIDIA forum - they're both from me and I see the answers are both from you :)